# Android Wear: Manifest merger failed for Notification Sample

Tags: android, wear-os

I was trying to compile the Notification sample for Android wear in Android Studio and got this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1] /Users/leojunquera/.android/build-cache/7d74b31b21417dab097f5cb22578f1fa83249896/output/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.gridlayout" to force usage

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and here you would find problematic `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8`.

It causes a problem as your project is already using Android Support libraries, which are available from `sdkVersion 9`.

Please go there and change from `8` to `9`.

Futhermore, please check your `build.gradle` files as here also may be the same problem.

Hope it will help